# React: problem on using props inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a functional component which receives props from Redux. In Redux, i have a function for load users, what i want to do is load users inside a dropdown when component starts, and it happens in the current code, but the following warning appears in console:

[image]

My code:

```
function GroupInfo(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.requestLoadUsers()
    }, [])

    return  (    
         <form className="mx-5 mt-5">         
              <div className="btn-group dropdownUsuario">
                   <div className="dropdown-menu">
                       { props.users.map(user => {
                           return (
                               <button
                                   key={user.id}
                                   className="dropdown-item" 
                                   type="button">

                                   {user.firstName}
                               </button>
                           )
                       }) }
                   </div>
              </div>
       </form>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedGroup: state.group.selectedGroup,
        users: state.groupInfo.users.rows
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        requestLoadUsers: () => dispatch(requestLoadUsers())
    }
}
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(GroupInfo)
```

If i put '`props`' inside brackets, the warning gones, but my component starts making requests every time, because it will update each change in props, example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.requestLoadUsers()
}, [props])
```

**ps:** i also tried `[props.requestLoadUsers]`, but the warning stills

How can i avoid the warning whitout infinite requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destruct props, So you can change your component to this:

```
function GroupInfo({requestLoadUsers, ...props}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        requestLoadUsers();
    }, [requestLoadUsers]);

    return (
        <form className="mx-5 mt-5">
            <div className="btn-group dropdownUsuario">
                <div className="dropdown-menu">
                    {props.users.map(user => {
                        return (
                            <button key={user.id} className="dropdown-item" type="button">
                                {user.firstName}
                            </button>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```